# I want to my if condition to work on all records in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, loops, if-statement

I am new in laravel and i am making a quiz app where there are four possible answers of a question and one is correct .The questions and answers are stored in database,
my code works only on one question.

**This is my code in controller**

```
public function answerQuestions(Request $request){
    $answers =$request->all();
    $getAnswer=Question::where('ans',[$request->ans])->get();

    if ($getAnswer->isEmpty()) { 
       return back()->withErrors(['fail' => ['Wrong Answer']]);
    }
    else {
       return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'your Answer is Correct'); 
    }
}
```

Can anybody please help me...

Comment: What is your request ?

Comment: the data in request is in the form of an array

Answer (score 0):

you should key all answers the same name as answer[] in form because you have to check the each answer with the each question right.

you should write this code

```
$answers=$request->answer;
$rightQuestions=[];
foreach($answers as $answer)
{
    $questions= Question::all();
     foreach($questions as $question)
    {
         if($question->ans==$answer)
         {
              $rightQuestions=$answer;
         }
    }
     
}
```

returning back you should send the right question array and you can show the right questions

Comment: Now I get This.. 
ErrorException
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

Comment: sorry my bad..  please do this  $questions = Questions::all();

Comment: I've already switch get() with all() but it still works on first question

Comment: ok try one more thing..foreach($answers as $key=>$answer)
{
     if($question=Question::where('id',$key)->where('ans',$answer)->first())
     {
       $rightQuestions=$question->id;
     }
}

Comment: I am Tired bro it still not working it shows nothing

Comment: write your full code of a function in controller so i can see what are you doing exactly

Comment: after some changes in the code i got what i want but the problen is it still get first question it is not checking the second question

Comment: loop only works on first question and i want it to work the same functionality on all questions

Comment: please put you whole function of controller please

Comment: class QuestionController extends Controller
{
    public function startQ(){
        $users = question::limit(2)->get(); return view('answerDesk',['users'=>$users]);}
public function answerQuestions(Request $request){$answers=$request->answer; $rightQuestions=[$request->ans];  if (is_array($answers)|| is_object($answers)) { foreach($answers as $answer){ $questions= Question::all(); foreach($questions as $question){ if($question->ans==$answer){return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'your Answer is Correct');}return back()->withErrors(['fail' => ['Wrong Answer']]);}}}